# Oracle Apex 21.2 - Page Item Source vs Computation

Tags: oracle-apex21.2

Are there any rules of thumb on when to use one over the other? I have a page item `P2_STUDENT_ID`, that can either get set from another page using a URL redirect or needs to get a default value from SQL if not coming from that page and is null in session state.

Is it better to use a computation for the page item or the page item's source to set this default value? What are the pros and cons of each, or is it just a matter of preference?